# Disposing of an Object that is used repeatedly

Tags: c#, object, garbage-collection, dispose

I have looked around, and I cannot find what is the best practice for this. I have a loop that creates an object and then disposes of it each time a process is run. However, this object is always the same and is used in the program every minute or so, which is also how often the other processes in the program run. Should I call `Dispose();` on this object every time the process is run or just keep it since it is always exactly the same? The language is C#.

Comment: Unless you actually tell us what your IDisposable actually is, any answers will be speculative and ***may*** not apply to your situation. For instance if your IDisposable is a DataContext such as exist in Linq2Sql or EF, then you'll accumulate ObjectTracking data if you don't dispose, which may or may not be desired.

Comment: It is a `ReaderManagement` object from a Motorola RFID API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it works the way you've written it, seems like you shouldn't change it. Unless the object is particularly expensive to create or destroy. But if you don't need the object except during that brief period every minute, why keep it around?

Look at it this way. If the object is only used by that one particular task, then having that task control the object's lifetime makes for simpler code. Otherwise your main program will have to create the object at startup and dispose of it at shutdown. Also, other threads or tasks within the program then potentially have access to it. Restricting access to just the task that needs it can prevent a whole host of other problems.

Comment: Thanks. I'm glad that you brought up the point about other threads or tasks possibly having access to it if not disposed of, as this is something that I certainly do not want for this particular object.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep it somewhere if it takes a long time to initialize.

Depending on what the object is, you might also want to consider making it a [singleton.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)  Singletons are particularly useful when you have an object that takes a long time to initialize, and/or if the object is used in multiple places.

Comment: Singletons are event nastier when the object is disposable and particularly resource intensive; it makes it *much* more likely that it will be kept around for longer than it needs to be, or will even not be disposed at all.

Comment: The reason I mentioned singleton is because I used it in a context that sounded like OP's.  I had a geocoder(which loaded a bunch of shape files...took several seconds), and I only wanted one copy of the object using these files.  Otherwise, I would need to be concerned about data consistency.  Part of the program's requirement was to have a heart beat monitor of the geocoder, to make sure it was still running periodically.

Comment: @Servy: Keeping a resource around indefinitely will either have a certain cost or be Just Plain Unacceptable.  Regenerating a resource repeatedly will have a certain cost.  If the cost of keeping a resource around indefinitely would be known, and would be lower than the cost of regenerating it repeatedly, then keeping it around as long as circumstances suggest that it will be needed often may be wise.  If it will be needed often throughout the lifetime of the program, there may be nothing wrong with keeping it alive for that duration.

Answer (score 0):

Create the object only once and call dispose on closing youre app.
It also depends a little on what you're doing.

Comment: And why should he do this?  You say it depends, but don't say *what it depends on*.  He's specifically asking how he should scope it, and you haven't given him any information as to how to make that decision, you've only told him to do one thing and then say that it may not even be right.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should be looking at the using statement. It disposes the object after use.
[See this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664736%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

this is the syntax

```
using (var myObject = new MyCustomObject())
{
//Do something with my object
}
```

Comment: What's to say he's not already using a `using`?  And regardless of whether he is or isn't, this isn't answering the question that he's asking.

Comment: Well, I was just trying to help. That's why there is a mark as answer button by every proposed answer. He has the option of choosing the one that answers his question. Since you took time to criticise almost everyone's answer, maybe you should have invested time in providing a solution yourself.

Comment: I have no need to provide my own answer because someone else actually provided an answer that answers the question instead of a low quality non-answer.  Perhaps you could take the time to address my criticism and either fix your post or explain why you post is proper, or perhaps even answer the question that has been asked instead of criticizing me for providing constructive criticism to several very low quality answers.  If you would like to provide helpful information but aren't willing to put the time/effort into a quality answer you can post a comment; this would be an appropriate comment.

Comment: Well I wont want to drag this along so I will leave you with a few things to think about before criticising others. The question did not state that he had tried the approach that I have stated above. How do you expect me to assume that for him? Also you should know, that most of the people who post anything on here are all here to learn new things. So even though an answer may be "low quality" in your opinion, it may actually be solving someone else's question in the   future. Just add an answer if you know anything "at all". Else keep quiet and read on. Have a nice day.

Comment: I'm not asserting that the OP was using this, I'm saying it doesn't matter if he was or was not using this before.  He asked a question about how to appropriately scope his object.  **You didn't answer that question**.  On top of that, depending on where he decides to scope the object, using a `using` may not even be *possible*.  You shouldn't be posting an answer to a question to post unrelated information that you think might be useful to someone.  How will they find it? You can post a comment with that info if you'd like, or find a question to which that information is a valid answer.

Comment: U just said "may not". Do you know what "may not" even means? My answer my be low quality, but am glad to hear u say it "may not" be helpful to the one who posted the question. At least it "may be" helpful to someone else who has a problem that requires my answer.

Comment: Sure, and punching someone in the face just because you feel like it might be helpful.  It's unlike, but it's possible.  That doesn't mean it's appropriate to do.  This is not appropriate content to post as an answer because it doesn't answer the question.  If you would like to post a comment that doesn't answer the question but may be helpful, post a comment, or find a question for which your information is a valid answer (or post a new question if there are none for which it's a valid answer).  It's not appropriate to just post random information to an unrelated question.

Comment: Just get of my case yeah. You are flooding my email inbox.

Comment: And just to say, what is this talk of something being an appropriate answer. He wanted to dispose the object anyway, isn't that one of the uses of the "using" statement? Am not the only one who posted this answer. so it means at least two people found it wise to suggest the using statement as an answer. Unfortunately, one person who claims to be the God of all appropriate answers did not even attempt to answer the question, but found it necessary to criticize others. Like I said, what's done is done. Just don't belittle other people's opinions when they aren't what you'd expect them to be.

Comment: He's not asking how to dispose of an object, he's not indicating that he's having problem with the object not being disposed that would be solved by using a `using` statement, he's asking at what scope it's appropriate to dispose of the object.  **What's your answer to that question?**  You have none.  Using a `using` doesn't tell him how he should scope his disposable object at all.  I'm not saying the answer is wrong, I'm saying that the answer *doesn't even attempt to answer the question*.  It's like you didn't even read the question at all.